# How to prove this formula of Identical balls in identical bins?

Tags: combinatorics

[image]

I tried recursion by my own way using partioning, but can't get the result. It must have also used that distributing in r groups is equal to distributing when r is the maximum group, but can't understand how that T(n-1,k-1) came.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That formula comes from splitting into two cases:

- some bin contains exactly one ball (then there are $T(n-1,k-1)$ arrangements for the rest;
- every bin contains at least two balls (then removing one ball from every bin we get an arrangement with $k$ bins and $n-k$ balls).